# android getAppWidgetIds failed, what wrong?

Tags: android

I want to use following code to get a widget id, but getAppWidgetIds always return an empty array, the num is always 0, what wrong?

Thanks!

```
public class test extends Activity implements  OnTouchListener {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         .....

        AppWidgetManager mAppWidgetManager; 
    AppWidgetHost mAppWidgetHost; 

        mAppWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext());

        ComponentName THIS_APPWIDGET =new ComponentName("com.android.music", "com.android.music.MediaAppWidgetProvider");       

        int[] appWidgetId=mAppWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(THIS_APPWIDGET);
        int num=appWidgetId.length;
```

Comment: I suppose that you cannot access widgets created by another applications...

Answer (score 9):

Use

```
new ComponentName(context, com.android.music.MediaAppWidgetProvider.class)
```

instead.

Comment: Worked for me, even though I debugged the previous Component I constructed with the classnames, and it matched the ComponentName returned in 
AppWidgetProviderInfo  getAppWidgetInfo(int appWidgetId)